# Asp.net Required filed validator

Tags: asp.net

I am using requiredfield validator for the telerik textbox, while clearing the values in client side it is being validated, but i dont want to validate while resetting the form. Tried causesvalidaton = false, but not seem to work out, plesae help on this.

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtSubscriberName" runat="server" Width="60%" Skin="Outlook" ValidationGroup="SelectionFormValidationGroup" ValidateRequestMode="Inherit" EmptyMessage="Enter Subscriber Name" MaxLength="50" onkeyup="changeCase(this)"></telerik:RadTextBox
```

This is my javascript code
var radtextbox $find('<%=txtSubscriberName.ClientID %>'); radtextbox.clear();

Comment: Please show us your code and what you have tried so far!

Comment: change validation group and check reset button is not calling any js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disable the validator temporarily from client-side after you have cleared it you can do it with `ValidatorEnable`:

```
var validator = document.getElementById('ValidatorID');
ValidatorEnable(validator, false);
```

Comment: Hi this is working perfectly,but one more problem occurs...once i disable the validator when i try to add new record validator will not work. So i have to enable again right.

Comment: If the page posts back to server it should be enabled again automatically. If that happens on clientside you need to enable it again.

Comment: It is working perfectly. Thank you so much for showing interest in my query.